# Escape special characters in reStructuredText Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

For my documentation, I want escape special characters.

Example :

```
.. code-block:: terminal

    $ php bin/console test:user

    Press <return> for continue
```

For Sphinx, it's an external URL `<return>` and I want escape that.

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I want escape <return>, because in render  Press <return> is showing different than for continue.

Comment: Different how? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this output. The only problem I notice when using your code-block is this message: "WARNING: Pygments lexer name 'terminal' is not known". And that is true, there is no such lexer. See http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/. I think you should use "console" instead.

Comment: Content of a code block is not parsed as rST. Instead, the "pygments" parser adds syntax highlight based on the given code language. I daubt `<return>` it is recocnized as external URL. The HTML source for code line 3 might help to tell what it is parsed as. (I cannot reproduce the problem here.)

Answer (score 5):

See [Escaping Mechanism](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism):

> A backslash followed by any character (except whitespace characters in non-URI contexts) escapes that character. The escaped character represents the character itself, and is prevented from playing a role in any markup interpretation. The backslash is removed from the output.

To answer your question, you can use various markup techniques.

Escape the opening and closing brackets.

```
Press \<return\> for continue
```

Use inline literal markup.

```
Press ``<return>`` for continue
```

Use [semantic markup with the `kbd` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-kbd):

```
Press :kbd:`<return>` for continue
```

IMO, the last option is the most appropriate for this situation.  The first option is the least appropriate.

Comment: Doesn't work, i forget mentionned a detail, i edited my question sorry.

Comment: :kbd: and double backticks don't work if the character you're trying to escape is a literal backslash e.g. in a windows style file path. Found using double backslashes was the only solution

Comment: Escaping and inline markup do not work inside a "code" or "code-block" directive.